# How do I remove backslash from users input

Tags: php, mysql, backslash

I'm getting blur to this one :P

```
function escape($string)
{
    $string = stripslashes($string);

    if (function_exists('mysql_real_escape_string')) {
       return mysql_real_escape_string($string, $this->connection);
    } else {
        return mysql_escape_string($string);
    }
}

$content = '""""""test\'te%%%%st`test_huhu\'_';

echo '<br>output 1 = '.stripslashes($content);
echo '<br>output 2 = '.$db->escape($content);
```

The output

```
output 1 =  """"""test'te%%%%st`test_huhu'_
output 2 =  \"\"\"\"\"\"test\'te%%%%st`test_huhu\'_
```

How to make `output 2` will be same like `output 1` and why the **`output 2`** to be like that?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Output 2 has all quotes escaped with `mysql_real_escape_string()`.  If that's not what you want, don't do it.

Comment: I'm confused.  Output 2 seems to be a prepared string ready to be inserted into a mysql database.  After the insert and subsequent select query, the slashes will not be present.

Comment: @Stephen - yes, but data will stored to db exactly with output 2

Comment: No, it will not.  It will be like output 1.  The slashes are there to tell the SQL parser that that's not the end of the string.  The slashes will not be in the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string` escapes all `"` and `'` that's why you get all those slashes. If you remove the slashes before putting the data in a database you're open for attacks which
is very bad for security dont you think?